# Tag overview in the Craft backend

Tags: tags

Is there a possibility or plugin that I can see all my tags that I am using on my Craft page?

So that I can edit the tags when I, for example, wrote some tags wrong or just want to delete some and so on.

All the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [Tag Manager](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/tagmanager) plugin you can use for this.

You might also want to consider voting for [this feature request](https://craftcms.uservoice.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7179221-tag-management) if you think this should be in core!

Comment: thanks. I already installed the plugin and works fine.
I will also vote for it that this is default in craft cms. Thx so far!